# Keycloak redirect_uri

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak, hostname

I have the problem, when request to login comes to Keycloak, in the redirect url there is a name of the server with the application like **l-server01**, but thats the **internal name**, so I cant access it from outside of the network. I want to have this name in the redirect url : **portal.application.com** for example. Dont you know how Keycloak resolves the **hostname** on which the secured application resides or where to setup jboss hostname?

This is not the problem with valid redirect urls. I have also tried to run JBOSS with -b parameter, but the redirect URL doesnt changed.

Comment: I tried to do Rewrite URL on Apache load balancer, betweeen application and Keycloak and I am able to change the redirect_url from internal name to www.external.name.com, but then I got error incorrect redirect uri when request come back to the application.. Is it even possible to run Keycloak and Application we would like to secure on 2 domains?  Thanks